# How to prevent contact child deletion when deleting a parent account?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In Microsoft Dynamics 365, I want to delete an account record but prevent the deletion of any child contacts that are in an active state. Contacts in inactive state should be deleted as normal. How can I achieve this using a plugin?

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Dynamics does not allow us to change the Cascading Delete in the Account to Contact 1-N relationship, which means that every time you delete an Account all the Contacts related to it will be deleted. This relationship cannot be deleted as well.

**EDIT:** Register the plugin below as a **PreValidation** Delete and it will work (Credit to @Sxntk for the idea of disassociating child records)

```
public class AccountPreDeletePlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        var pluginExecutionContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        var organizationServiceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        var organizationService = organizationServiceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(pluginExecutionContext.UserId);

        if (pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] is EntityReference entityReference)
        {
            var query = new QueryExpression("contact") { NoLock = true };
            query.Criteria.AddCondition("parentcustomerid", ConditionOperator.Equal, entityReference.Id);
            query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0);

            var entityCollection = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            if (entityCollection?.Entities?.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var entity in entityCollection.Entities)
                {
                    entity["parentcustomerid"] = null;
                    organizationService.Update(entity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but can't we achieve this using plugin??

Comment: Maybe you can disassociate the record before the contact is deleted with a plug-in

Comment: @Sxntk Yes that is a good idea and is doable in a pre-delete plugin.

Comment: Using a ExecuteMultipleRequest within plugins/CWAs it's not a best practice and it should be avoided: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/best-practices/business-logic/avoid-batch-requests-plugin